# Return only time irrelevant date javascript

Tags: javascript

My question is more about logic not code.I created something called prepared messages with time i supply to each new message, i compare the time with current time and give each row a background. Is it possible for me to fetch the time with javascript only the current time NO DATE.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

To compare only the time, without year, month and day taken into account, try the following:

```
var now = new Date().setFullYear(1, 0, 1)
,   andThen = new Date(dateMessageSent).setFullYear(1, 0, 1)

if (now > andThen) doYourStuff()
```

Comment: This is cool, but I would suggest setting year and day to `1` instead of `0`. This is because there are no year "0" or day "0". On the other hand, `month` is indexed from `0`, so there's no need to change that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see [Date.getTime()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getTime.asp)

Comment: That will return the number of milliseconds since 01 January, 1970 UTC

Answer (score 1):

```
d = new Date();
var time=d.toTimeString();
```

Comment: How would you remove the timezone information without resorting to regex / trim functions?

Comment: @codecowboy You can do like this `var time=d.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) and in particular the following methods

1. [toTimeString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_totimestring.asp)
2. [getHours()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp)
3. [getMinutes()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getminutes.asp)
4. [getSeconds()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getseconds.asp)